# Finding Area within an action event

Tags: java, user-interface, floor

I am writing a program for class, and I have about all of it done but one part that is really confusing me.

I have to create a system for flooring that a person can choose the floor type, enter their length and width of their floor and it calculates and produces a order summary.

Now, I am able to get all of this but the calculations correct (and I haven't even started on the database connection because of it.)

My professor is extremely vague in her directions and even the answers to her questions, so as a last ditch effort I thought I would try here.

I cannot for the life of me figure it out so ANY help is greatly appreciated.

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class FloorMart
{

    private static JFrame frame = null;

    private static Integer cost;
    private static String floorSize;
    private static String floorType;
    private double floorLength;
    private double floorWidth;


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        frame = new JFrame("FloorMart");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(320, 300);

        JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();

        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setText("Welcome to the FloorMart ordering system! ");
        panel1.add(jLabel);

        JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
        jLabel1.setText("Enter your Name: ");
        panel1.add(jLabel1);

        JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
        panel1.add(text1);

        JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
        jLabel2.setText("Enter your Pnone Number: ");
        panel1.add(jLabel2);

        JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
        panel1.add(text2);

        tPane.addTab("Customer", panel1);

        JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
        panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setText("Floor Type? ");
        panel2.add(jLabel);

        ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
        JRadioButton RadioButton = new JRadioButton("Carpet - $10 per sq ft",               true);
        panel2.add(RadioButton);
        group.add(RadioButton);

        JRadioButton RadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("Hardwood - $20 per sq ft");
        panel2.add(RadioButton1);
        group.add(RadioButton1);

        tPane.addTab("Floor Type", panel2);

        JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
        panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setText("Enter the length and width of your floor! ");
        panel3.add(jLabel);

        JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel();
        jLabel3.setText("Enter the floor length: ");
        panel3.add(jLabel3);

        JTextField length = new JTextField(10);
        panel3.add(length);
        //length.setText(cost.toString());  //


        JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel();
        jLabel4.setText("Enter the floor width: ");
        panel3.add(jLabel4);

        JTextField width = new JTextField(10);
        panel3.add(width);
        //width.setText(cost.toString()); //


        tPane.addTab("Floor Size", panel3);

        JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
        panel4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

        jLabel = new JLabel();
        jLabel.setText("Total Cost: ");
        panel4.add(jLabel);

        JTextField text3 = new JTextField(10);
        panel4.add(text3);

       JButton button = new JButton("Order Summary");
       button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
       {

           @Override
           public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
           {
               JPanel panelNew = new JPanel();
               panelNew.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelNew, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

               JLabel jLabeln = new JLabel("Order Summary");
               JLabel jLabeln1 = new JLabel("Customer Name: " + text1.getText());
               JLabel jLabeln2 = new JLabel("Phone Number: " + text2.getText());
               JLabel jLabeln3 = new JLabel("Floor Type: " + floorType);
               JLabel jLabeln4 = new JLabel("Floor Area: " + floorSize);
               JLabel jLabeln5 = new JLabel("Total: $" + new Double(cost) + "0");
               JLabel jLabeln6 = new JLabel("Thank you for shopping at FloorMart!");

                panelNew.add(jLabeln);
                panelNew.add(jLabeln1);
                panelNew.add(jLabeln2);
                panelNew.add(jLabeln3);
                panelNew.add(jLabeln4); 
                panelNew.add(jLabeln5);
                panelNew.add(jLabeln6);

                frame.invalidate();
                frame.remove(panel1);frame.remove(panel2);frame.remove(panel3);
                frame.remove(panel4);
                frame.remove(tPane);

                frame.add(panelNew);
                frame.revalidate();
                frame.repaint();

           }


       });

         panel4.add(button);
         tPane.addTab("Total", panel4);


         ChangeListener changeListener= new ChangeListener()
         {
             public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent changeEvent)
             {

                 JTabbedPane sourceTabbedPane = (JTabbedPane) changeEvent.getSource();
                 int index = sourceTabbedPane.getSelectedIndex();

                 if(index == 2)
                 {
                     double floorLength = Double.parseDouble(length.getText());
                     double floorWidth = Double.parseDouble(width.getText());
                     floorSize = floorLength * floorWidth;
                     if(RadioButton.isSelected())
                     {
                         cost = 10; //per sq ft
                         floorType = RadioButton.getText();

                     }
                     else if(RadioButton1.isSelected())
                     {
                         cost = 20; //per sq ft
                         floorType = RadioButton1.getText();
                     }

                     text3.setText(cost.toString());

                 }
             }

         };

         tPane.addChangeListener(changeListener);

         frame.add(tPane);
         frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see two basic things that needs to be changed: 

a. this does not compile (floorSize should be double)

```
     String floorSize;
     double floorLength = Double.parseDouble(length.getText());
     double floorWidth = Double.parseDouble(width.getText());
     floorSize = floorLength * floorWidth;
```

b. The calculation of floorSize should not be triggered by ChangeListener (which causes the calculation to be done before values are entered). 
Use "Order Summary" JButton to trigger the calculation.

Here is a working version of the code. See my comments:

```
    import java.awt.Dimension;
    import java.awt.FlowLayout;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

    import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
    import javax.swing.ButtonGroup;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.JRadioButton;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;

    public class FloorMart
    {

        private static JFrame frame = null;

        private static Integer cost;  //better use int

        //////////////////////////////////////
        //changed from string to double
        private static double floorSize;
        ////////////////////////////////////
        private static String floorType;
        private double floorLength;
        private double floorWidth;


        public static void main(String[] args)
        {

            frame = new JFrame("FloorMart");

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(320, 300);

            JTabbedPane tPane = new JTabbedPane();

            JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
            panel1.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            JLabel jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setText("Welcome to the FloorMart ordering system! ");
            panel1.add(jLabel);

            JLabel jLabel1 = new JLabel();
            jLabel1.setText("Enter your Name: ");
            panel1.add(jLabel1);

            JTextField text1 = new JTextField(10);
            panel1.add(text1);

            JLabel jLabel2 = new JLabel();
            jLabel2.setText("Enter your Pnone Number: ");
            panel1.add(jLabel2);

            JTextField text2 = new JTextField(10);
            panel1.add(text2);

            tPane.addTab("Customer", panel1);

            JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
            panel2.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setText("Floor Type? ");
            panel2.add(jLabel);

            ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
            JRadioButton RadioButton = new JRadioButton("Carpet - $10 per sq ft",               true);
            panel2.add(RadioButton);
            group.add(RadioButton);

            JRadioButton RadioButton1 = new JRadioButton("Hardwood - $20 per sq ft");
            panel2.add(RadioButton1);
            group.add(RadioButton1);

            tPane.addTab("Floor Type", panel2);

            JPanel panel3 = new JPanel();
            panel3.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setText("Enter the length and width of your floor! ");
            panel3.add(jLabel);

            JLabel jLabel3 = new JLabel();
            jLabel3.setText("Enter the floor length: ");
            panel3.add(jLabel3);

            JTextField length = new JTextField(10);
            panel3.add(length);
            //length.setText(cost.toString());  //


            JLabel jLabel4 = new JLabel();
            jLabel4.setText("Enter the floor width: ");
            panel3.add(jLabel4);

            JTextField width = new JTextField(10);
            panel3.add(width);
            //width.setText(cost.toString()); //


            tPane.addTab("Floor Size", panel3);

            JPanel panel4 = new JPanel();
            panel4.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
            panel4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));

            jLabel = new JLabel();
            jLabel.setText("Total Cost: ");
            panel4.add(jLabel);

            JTextField text3 = new JTextField(10);
            panel4.add(text3);

           JButton button = new JButton("Order Summary");
           button.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
           {

               @Override
               public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
               {

                   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   //calculation moved to here
                   double floorLength = Double.parseDouble(length.getText());
                   double floorWidth = Double.parseDouble(width.getText());
                   floorSize = floorLength * floorWidth;
                   if(RadioButton.isSelected())
                   {
                       cost = 10; //per sq ft
                       floorType = RadioButton.getText();

                   }
                   else if(RadioButton1.isSelected())
                   {
                       cost = 20; //per sq ft
                       floorType = RadioButton1.getText();
                   }

                   text3.setText(cost.toString());
                   //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

                   JPanel panelNew = new JPanel();
                   panelNew.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panelNew, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

                   JLabel jLabeln = new JLabel("Order Summary");
                   JLabel jLabeln1 = new JLabel("Customer Name: " + text1.getText());
                   JLabel jLabeln2 = new JLabel("Phone Number: " + text2.getText());
                   JLabel jLabeln3 = new JLabel("Floor Type: " + floorType);
                   JLabel jLabeln4 = new JLabel("Floor Area: " + floorSize);
                   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   // changed JLabel jLabeln5 = new JLabel("Total: $" + new Double(cost*floorSize) + "0");
                   //to:
                   JLabel jLabeln5 = new JLabel("Total: $" + new Double(cost*floorSize) + "0");
                   ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                   JLabel jLabeln6 = new JLabel("Thank you for shopping at FloorMart!");

                    panelNew.add(jLabeln);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln1);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln2);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln3);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln4);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln5);
                    panelNew.add(jLabeln6);

                    frame.invalidate();
                    frame.remove(panel1);frame.remove(panel2);frame.remove(panel3);
                    frame.remove(panel4);
                    frame.remove(tPane);

                    frame.add(panelNew);
                    frame.revalidate();
                    frame.repaint();

               }


           });

             panel4.add(button);
             tPane.addTab("Total", panel4);

             /////////////////////////////////
             //removed  ChangeListener
             ////////////////////////////////

             frame.add(tPane);
             frame.setVisible(true);

        }
    }
```